# If I perform an unwind segue (show), how can the mother view controller get the child's view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, segue

I'd like to check the type of view controller that performed the unwind segue.

In my mother controller, this is what I have:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let theChildView = segue. //what??
}
```

How do I check what class/type the child who called the unwind is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if segue.sourceViewController is ChildUIViewController{

}
```

or you can convert it

```
 if let child = segue.sourceViewController as? ChildUIViewController{

   }
```